# Can I have all the consumers of a group consume message from all the partitions of a kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Let's say in Kafka I have 4 partitions of a topic 'A' and I have 20 consumers of Consumer Group 'AC'. I don't need any ordering, but I want to process the messages faster by scaling my consumer instances. Please note all messages are independent and can be processed independently.

I looked at a consumer configuration `partition.assignment.strategy`, but not sure if I can achieve dynamic assignment of consumer to partition, depending on the message availability.

Answer (score 0):

One partition is assigned to exactly one consumer in the group. In your case you have only 4 consumers on 20 which are currently working. You have to increase partitions number if you want more assigned consumers.